# How do I get Indic options in Illustrator CS6?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

I'm trying to write in Hebrew, which is from right to left, on Illustrator CS6.
This is not working, and all my words are written backwards.
Everywhere I look it says to enable Indic options. However, Illustrator CS6 does not have this option.
Any idea how I can either install indic options or find some other way to write from right to left?

Comment: I believe you need the **multi-language version** for CS6.

Comment: @Scott: As in, buy another version of Illustrator?

Comment: **CS6** had 2 options.. An English version and a Multi-language version. The English version does not support many necessary issues with other languages. The Multi-language version was designed for use in Europe or Asia or anywhere which is not English. As for "buying another version"... you **can't** really buy CS6 today.. either version.. at least not legally or without a *great* deal of research to ensure you get a legal, transferred version. At a minimum you would need to *upgrade* to CC in most cases.

Comment: -- In short.. You probably **can't** do this in the English version of CS6. You may need to *manually* adjust things (as in type backwards) with an older, non-multi-language, version. -- But please **be aware** I'm **speculating** here. I have never used anything other than the English version and I have never needed Indic options.

Comment: Go to cc cloud app where you manage your apps and change the language to english/hebrew or english/arabic and install the app you want. That should give the RTL tools

Comment: @JulianSteinmann There is no "CC Cloud App" for **CS6**.

Comment: Oh misread this. Probably not possible anymore. Maybe contact Adobe support they may be able to help...